# Unsplit a list of data frames after subsetting the data frames in the list

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a data frame "x"

```
> x
    x1         x2 x3
1  box 0.81432465  4
2  box 0.19628122  2
3  box 0.06619734  1
4  box 0.90403568  5
5  box 0.52693274  3
6  axe 0.28665840  2
7  axe 0.45193228  3
8  axe 0.48278466  4
9  axe 0.86553847  5
10 axe 0.13925190  1
11 cat 0.86340413  5
12 cat 0.28387540  2
13 cat 0.24297445  1
14 cat 0.36651366  3
15 cat 0.55038108  4
```

Then I perform following operations on it

```
> x.factor <- factor(x[,1]) ## convert column 1 as factors
> x.split <- split(x, x.factor)
> unsplit(x.split, x.factor) ## get back original data frame
```

works fine till now. But when I do this, it gives me an error

```
> x.split2 <- lapply(x.split, function(x) {head(x,1)})
> unsplit(x.split2, x.factor) ## trying to combine into a data frame

Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1’, ‘11’, ‘6’
```

I don't get it because, if I print out x.split2, the row names are unique for each element in the list.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `unsplit`, you can use the common `do.call(rbind, ...)` approach:

```
do.call(rbind, x.split2)
#      x1        x2 x3
# axe axe 0.2866584  2
# box box 0.8143246  4
# cat cat 0.8634041  5
```

Your present approach doesn't work because your "x.factor" object has duplicated values that relate to the original number of rows in your `data.frame`. Since you're just taking one of each factor, you can also try something like the following:

```
unsplit(x.split2, levels(x.factor))
#     x1        x2 x3
# 6  axe 0.2866584  2
# 1  box 0.8143246  4
# 11 cat 0.8634041  5
```